# Converting bil image into grid using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, convert, esri-grid-format

I've downloaded [RFE data from FEWSNET](http://earlywarning.usgs.gov/fews/africa/). It's a compressed file which includes .bil files.

Now I want to convert this ".bil image" into a grid to use the precipitation data in an area.

I'm using ArcMap.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 and was able to convert a BIL file downloaded from [FEWSNET](http://earlywarning.usgs.gov/fews/africa/web/datatheme.php) to a GRID format using the [Raster To Other Format (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000032000000) tool.

I downloaded and unzipped the ZIP file to find the BIL file, then opened the tool.

I chose the BIL file as my Input Raster, and set the Output Workspace to a folder where I had write access (C:\temp) and the Raster Format (for output) to GRID.